# How can I check if the mouse clicked over a defined Object

Tags: java, menu

I'm making a game in java and I tried to make a class for my gui button, but I don't know how to check when the button is clicked! I know how to use MouseListener but is there an easier way to do it?

Code:
Button.java

```
package galaxyblast.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Button {

protected int x;
protected int y;
protected int width;
protected int height;

public Button(String label, int x, int y, int width, int height, Graphics2D g2d, Graphics g){
    Rectangle btn = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    Font font2 = new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 30);
    g.setFont(font2);
    g.drawString(label, x + width / 20, y + height-height/3);
    g2d.draw(btn);

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Bounds getBounds(){
    Bounds bounds = new Bounds(x, y, width, height);
    return bounds;
}
final class Bounds{
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public Bounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }


    }
}
```

Usage Sample:

```
package galaxyblast.gui.debug;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import galaxyblast.gui.Button;
import galaxyblast.gui.Gui;

public class DebugMenu extends Gui{

boolean toggled = false;

public Button debugBtn;
public Button testBtn;

String menuName;

public DebugMenu(String menuName) {
    super(menuName);
    this.menuName = menuName;
}


@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {        
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    debugBtn = new Button("Debug", 60, 130, 100, 50, g2d, g);

    Font font0 = new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50);
    g.setFont(font0);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawString(menuName, 60,  60);
}

public boolean isToggled() {
    return toggled;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return menuName;
}

}
```

Is there a way of checking the click within the button or gui class?
Edit: This is on  a java Canvas

Comment: An easier way is to use Swing.

Comment: Mouse listener *is* the easier way of doing this. If you need to specify it more, you can do it via mouse listener as well.

Comment: I'm looking to see if there is a way to test within the actual Button or Gui class

Comment: You can use an IDE like Netbeans, which will generate most of the code for you.